# I have a issue about execute in python flask

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I am new in build python api. I want to get the data depend on date.

https://programminghistorian.org/en/lessons/creating-apis-with-python-and-flask#what-is-an-api

I am following this link to code my api but I don't know what can I do in execute.

This is my python code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["DEBUG"] = True

app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = 'localhost'
app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = 'MyDB'
app.config['MYSQL_charset'] ='utf8'

mysql = MySQL(app)

@app.route('/',methods = ['GET','POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == "POST":
        details = request.form
        firstday = details['firstday']
        lastday = details['lastday']
        cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
        cur.execute("select * from transaction join transaction_item on transaction.id = transaction_item.transaction_id join customer on customer.id = transaction.customer_id where transaction_datetime <= lastday and transaction_datetime >= firstday VALUES (%s, %s)", (firstday, lastday))
        mysql.connection.commit()
        cur.close()
        return 'success'
    return render_template('index.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

This is my HTML code:

```
<HTML>
    <BODY bgcolor="cyan">
    <form method="POST" action="">
        <center>
        <H1>Enter your details </H1> <br>
        first_transaction_datetime <input type = "text" name= "firstday" /> <br>
        last_transaction_datetime <input type = "text" name= "lastday" /> <br>
        <input type = "submit">
        </center>
    </form>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are sending requests to a back-end it does not fill out the form an easy way to do it would be to add the query values in the URL

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/?firstName=<firstName>&lastName=<lastName>
```

then your python code would look something like this.

```
@app.route('/',methods = ['GET','POST'])
def index():
    firstName = request.args.get('firstName')
    lastName = request.args.get('lastName')
    if request.method == "POST":
        # Do stuff here
```